# Connect web application with magento website

Tags: application

I have created magento based ecommerece website. Now i am creating a php based web application for website operations. i want to add option to import products, update price inventory everything from php application. But unable to connect. please guide me. I want to add more options in application.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can use API for that, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html